# Find and replace in scheme

Tags: list, recursion, scheme

I need to write a scheme program that finds and replaces a given pattern and I've gotten it to work on only one layer of nesting but when the next car from the list is a list itself, my program doesn't properly recurse in it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
(define replace 
    (lambda (source target replacement) 
        (if (eqv? source target)
            replacement
            (if (null? source)
                '() ;;base case

                (if (equal? target (car source))
                    (cons replacement (replace (cdr source) target replacement))

                    (cons (car source)
                    (replace (cdr source) target replacement))
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace (source target replacement) function in scheme - don't know if each argument is an atom or a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948835/replace-source-target-replacement-function-in-scheme-dont-know-if-each-argu)

Comment: Kind of a duplicate, the only difference is that this one is solved and the other isn't. (that may or may not be a good thing depending on how you look at it :))

Comment: Since you use `eqv?` it will only work on atoms in the first term. Use `equal?` for finding similar looking lists and vectors. Instead of checking for null, check for `(not (pair? source))` and return `source`. The alternative then will always be a pair and you should `cons` together the result from replacing the `car` and replacing the `cdr`. Your ending parenthesis shouldn't be on their own line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my initial version I was not checking to see if (car source) was a list and it was thereby being treated as an individual token, to avoid that I added one more condition:

```
(define replace 
    (lambda (source target replacement) 
        (if (eqv? source target)
            replacement
            (if (null? source)
                '() ;;base case

                (if (equal? target (car source))
                    (cons replacement (replace (cdr source) target replacement))

                    (if (not (list? (car source)))
                        (cons (car source) (replace (cdr source) target replacement))
                        (cons (replace (car source) target replacement) (replace (cdr source) target replacement))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use should replace `eqv?` with `equal?`.  Using `eqv?` doesn't give the result you'd expect as in the following:

```
> (eqv? (list 1 2 3) (list 1 2 3))
#f
> (eqv? '(1 2) '(1 2))
#f ; some Schemes may return #t
```

Regarding your code, it is more readably and compactly written as a series of `cond` clauses:

```
(define (replace source target replacement) 
  (cond ((eqv? source target) replacement)
        ((null? source)      '()) ;;base case
        ((equal? target (car source))
         (cons replacement (replace (cdr source) target replacement)))
        ((not (list? (car source)))
         (cons (car source) (replace (cdr source) target replacement)))
        (else
         (cons (replace (car source) target replacement) 
               (replace (cdr source) target replacement)))))
```

Also, another approach that might more clearly illustrate the algorithm ('handle `car` and cons it to handing of `cdr`') is:

```
(define (replace source target replacement)
  (cond ((null? source)'())
        ((equal? source target) replacement)
        (else (let ((next (car source))
                    (rest (cdr source)))
                (cons (if (not (list? next))
                          next
                          (replace next target replacement))
                      (replace rest target replacement)))))
```

Comment: The solution that I posted below is what worked for me. The purpose of the eqv was to handle cases that are not lists as this is intended to be a general replace function. Although I do appreciate the style tips you gave.

Comment: If you use eqv? in your code then `(replace '(a b) '(a b) 'x)` will return `'(a b)` instead of `x`.  (Although it may depend on your Scheme version, mine certainly returns `'(a b)`.)

Comment: Just tested it and yes you are correct, equal? is the proper choice.

Comment: I posted this question and my solution with the intent of giving myself the checkmark, your addition is nice but it wasn't the first solution posted to this problem.

Comment: You missed the 'eqv?'.  Hint: delete the question when you've answered it yourself and especially when it is homework.  You run the risk of getting down-votes and a closure.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you don't do replace on the `car` when it's not a match and it's not an atom. It's possible to write this very compact by allowing to follow all pairs.

```
(define (replace source target replacement) 
  (cond ((equal? source target) replacement) ;; equal, return replacement
        ((not (pair? source)) source)        ;; not equal && not pair, return source
        (else (cons (replace (car source) target replacement) ;; recurse
                    (replace (cdr source) target replacement)))))
```